# Connection error(10061) during web scraping occasionally

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, url, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use `beautifulsoup` to do web scraping.It ran perfectly fine at first, but an error occurred when I run my same code again.

Then i use `pd.read_html` instead of beautifulsoup to do web scraping, but the same connection error occurred(occasionally).

Code I tried:

```
link = 'https://www.twse.com.tw/block/BFIAUU?response=html&date=20190702&selectType=S'
f = urllib.urlopen(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')
pf = pd.read_html(link)[0]
```

**Error message:**

> [Error no 10061]No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it

Comment: can you provide the link to recreate the problem?

Comment: @ans2human
https://www.twse.com.tw/block/BFIAUU?response=html&date=20190702&selectType=S

Comment: This happens most often when you are using a restricted network like work or school. Are you trying through your personal internet connection?

Comment: @SachinPrabhu
Yes I'm trying through work,is there any solution to this.
Also, I would like to ask why sometimes it works, but sometimes it doesn't work?.Thx

Comment: Ask your IT team to provide proxy address. Then you can specify proxy within your request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simultaneously accessing some website that do not fall in the category of the websites you should access from your connection, server will not access the website. you can still do it using VPN.\

Instead of `urllib` go for [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/). Install it with `pip install requests`

```
import requests    

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36'}
link = 'https://www.twse.com.tw/block/BFIAUU?response=html&date=20190702&selectType=S'
f = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = bs(f.text,'html.parser')
th = [i.text.strip() for i in  (soup.find_all('th'))]
td =  [i.text for i in (soup.find_all('td'))]
print(th, td)
```

---

Your `pandas` code is perfectly fine, just don't use it along `urllib`. If you face the same error just incorporate some delay in your concurrent requests to scrape this page using python's `sleep` module.

e.g

```
import time
import pandas

while True:
    link = 'https://www.twse.com.tw/block/BFIAUU?response=html&date=20190702&selectType=S'
    pf = pd.read_html(link)[0:10]
    print(pf)
    time.sleep(1)  # delays for 1 second
```